# Deactivate LSTM memory in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm running some experiments on what role does the memory of an LSTM cell play in a sequence to sequence mapping.

Thus, I'm experimenting with LSTMs in Tensorflow v1.1 ([LSTM Cell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell)) and I would like to know if there's a way **to deactivate or tweak the memory of those cells**.

If I understood [this post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) correctly, I may be able to set the **forget gate** to 0 and the LSTM should forget everything but I don't know how to do it using Tensorflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with the `forget_bias` parameter of LSTM Cell

Comment: Also, if you wish to deactivate the memory, why don't you use a Traditional NN instead of a Recurrent one?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I'll take a look at the `forget_bias` parameter. Thanks!

Comment: About deactivating the memory, I could use a basic RNN cell but I prefer keeping my LSTM and simply tweak a few parameters. Also, as I'm doing seq2seq learning, I don't see the point of using a regular NN.